# webView em iOS não está acessando alguns sites

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview, apple

estou tentando desenvolver um aplicativo em iOS utilizando a linguagem objective-c. Porém eu tenho um dominio *.metaweb* que preciso que ele acesse não está carregando. Notei que alguns sites como por exemplo *facebook*, *globoesporte*, *espn* ele também não carrega, porém *google*, *linkedin*, *yahoo* ele acessa. O código que estou utilizando é:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.metaweb.com.br"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[_webView loadRequest:request];
```

Vocês tem alguma ideia do que pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: Qual a versão do iOS que você está utilizando?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O iOS 9 por padrão bloqueia conexões HTTP. Para habilita-las, abra o arquivo Info.plist em modo texto (click com o botão direito, Open As/Source Code) e adicione a seguinte configuração dentro do dicionário, na raiz:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: Apesar de funcionar o recomendável é adicionar uma lista dos domínios que o seu app precisa ter acesso usando NSExceptionDomains

Answer (score 0):

Para uma solução em Swift, recomendo usar o [CSafariWebKit](https://github.com/dmandarino/CSafariWebKit)

No seu arquivo

```
import CSafariWebKit
```

E no lugar que quiser chamar a WebView

```
let vc = SafariViewController(url: url, barTintColor: nil, tintColor: nil)
vc.presentSafari(fromViewController: self, whenDidFinish: nil)
```

Use as cores do seu app para uma melhor experiência.