# UIWebView acesso diferente do Google

Tags: ios, swift

O meu `webView` acessa perfeitamente o Google, mas se tento acessar uma outra página como o meu site ou um endereço local, ele fica a tela branca.

```
class ConectViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
    var urlPath : String = "https://afurlan.com.br" // cria url - possivel erro no colocar o https (pode colocar http)

    func loadAddressURL () { // cria funcão
        let requestURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)
        webView.loadRequest(request) // carrega
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadAddressURL()
    }
}
```

No log do Xcode da o seguinte texto :

> Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it
>   is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's
>   Info.plist file.

Comment: Você já adicionou permissão para acesso às conexões HTTP? Veja [esta resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/91170/4337).

Comment: fiz isto agora e acabei de testar e verificar com sucesso... Por favor escreva isto em uma resposta para definir como resolvido Obrigado