# Carregar WebView em Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, webview

Montei uma interface builder para carregar uma webview, com .h, .m e .xib.
Em um menu lateral, ao clicar em uma opcao, preciso chamar esta webview. Rodando a aplicacao, ao clicar nesta opcao me retorna o erro "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" na main.m.

.h file:

```
#ifndef WebViewCadastro_h
#define WebViewCadastro_h


#endif /* WebViewCadastro_h */


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface WebViewCadastro : UIViewController{
    IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWebView *webView;

@end
```

.m file:

```
#import "WebViewCadastro.h"

@implementation WebViewCadastro

-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *urlAddress = @"https://www.google.com.br";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
}

@end
```

.xib file:

[image: .xib]

Chamada da nib:

```
if([SINControler userLogado] == nil){
                [SINControler setUserLogado:nil];

 WebViewCadastro *curriculocontroller = [[WebViewCadastro alloc]
                    initWithNibName:@"WebViewCadastro" bundle:nil];

                UINavigationController *navigationController = self.menuContainerViewController.centerViewController;
                NSArray *controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:curriculocontroller];
                navigationController.viewControllers = controllers;
                [self.menuContainerViewController setMenuState:MFSideMenuStateClosed];
                [self.menuContainerViewController setLeftMenuViewController:nil];
```

Estou cometendo algum erro evidente? Alguma solução disponível?
Obrigada.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Está faltando conectar o outlet 'view' da interface com o File's Owner. Da mesma forma que você fez com 'webView'.

Comment: Obrigada. Agora ele abre a webview, mas não carrega a página do google. Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Provavelmente é por causa das configurações do App Transport Security (ATS). https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/91156/webview-em-ios-n%C3%A3o-est%C3%A1-acessando-alguns-sites/91170#91170