# Swift 3 em diante não aceita http?

Tags: ios, swift, http, webview

Li que depois do ano de 2017 a Apple não aceita mais http no swift + xcode.

Como fazer para acessar um domínio, usando um webview que ainda tenha http. Exemplo, no método post da minha página contem um http, o webview precisa acessa essa url, porém quando tento fazer o acesso, o xcode diz que bloqueou o acesso.

Estou utilizando a versão 10 do xcode, e nesta no info.plist não tem mais a opção de fazer a liberação.

Comment: Você já tentou esta solução? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/91156/webview-em-ios-n%C3%A3o-est%C3%A1-acessando-alguns-sites/91170#91170

Comment: obrigado Rafael, deu certo. Se eu publicar meu app na Apple Store, pode bloquear por essa configuração do http que acabei de fazer?

Comment: É possível. Caso você esteja acessando uma url específica via HTTP, é recomendado limitar o acesso inseguro apenas a essa url ou domínio usando NSExceptionDomains

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa definir a chave NSAllowsArbitraryLoads como YES no dicionário NSAppTransportSecurity em seu arquivo .plist.

Abra seu .plist -> clique em + na raiz -> Adicione a seguinte linha: `NSAppTransportSecurity`, assim que adicionar clique no + dp `App Transport Security Settings` (é o mesmo que acabamos de adicionar) e adicione essa linha filha: `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads`. deixe-a como YES.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]